# with presto how to show tables like XXX

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I have table `zzzbbb` in schema `s` and the `show tables from s;` works. 
But if there are lots of  tables in schema `s`, it will take time to find the right table.

The [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/show-tables.html) said that the `pattern` could help, but how to use it in detail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`SHOW TABLES LIKE pattern` behaves like a typical `SQL` `LIKE` operator:

% - The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters

_ - The underscore represents a single character

See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp.

```
presto:tiny> show tables like 'n_tion';
 Table
--------
 nation
(1 row)

presto:tiny> show tables like 'n%';
 Table
--------
 nation
(1 row)
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that in some databases (eg Hive) `SHOW TABLE LIKE <pattern>` does *not* behave like SQL's `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

For those working with Athena and ending up here, please see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-tables.html

It uses `*` instead of `%`.

For example - `SHOW TABLES IN sampledb '*flights*'`